# DBMS Pl/SQL -- What would be output ... please explain?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, error-handling, plsql

SQL> DESC hostel;

```
Name                                      Null?             Type 
    ------------------------------------  --------          ------------------- 
    HOSTELID                              NOT NULL          VARCHAR2(4) 
    ROOMSAVAILABLE                                              NUMBER(3) 
    HOSTELTYPE                                              VARCHAR2(1) 
    HOSTELFEE                                               NUMBER(6)
```

SQL> SELECT * FROM hostel;

```
HOST    ROOMSAVAILABLE      H       HOSTELFEE 
------- ---------------------- ----     --------------------- 
H1              2           M           2000 
H2              3           F           3000
```

Above is shown a table hostel and values in it.
What would be the output of following pl/sql program?
please explain in detail.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_validatehostelid 
(p_hostelid IN hostel.hostelid%TYPE, 
p_hostelfee OUT hostel.hostelfee%TYPE 
) 
IS 
v_count NUMBER; 
v_hostelfee hostel.hostelfee%TYPE; 
BEGIN 
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM hostel WHERE hostelid=p_hostelid; 
IF v_count=0 THEN 
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Invalid Hostel id'); 
ELSE 
SELECT hostelfee INTO v_hostelfee FROM hostel WHERE hostelid=p_hostelid; 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hostel Fee:'||v_hostelfee); 
END IF; 
EXCEPTION 
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No data found'); 
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Other Errors in Procedure'); 
END sp_validatehostelid; 
Procedure created. 

DECLARE 
g_hostelfee hostel.hostelfee%TYPE; 
BEGIN 
sp_validatehostelid('H5',g_hostelfee); 
EXCEPTION 
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Other Errors in Block'); 
END;
```

Comment: Please run it and see for yourself !

Answer (score 2):

> "What will be the output? given that there is no row having hostelid =
>   'H5'"

Assuming you run this in a client with serveroutput enabled the output will be

```
Other Errors in Procedure
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Why?

1. The first select statement is a count, which cannot hurl a NO_DATA_FOUND exception.
2. The next line raises a user-defined exception, -20000.
3. This passes control to the exception handler block.  -20000 is not NO_DATA_FOUND so the WHEN OTHERS clause is executed, which displays the message above.
4. The exception handler does not raise an exception itself, which is very bad practice.  So the flow returns to the calling block.
5. Because no exception was found the calling block thinks the called procedure executed successfully, and so processing terminate cleanly.  That's why it is bad practice not re-raise exceptions.

Note that if you run this without enabling serveroutput first the output will be:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_validatehostelid 
(
    p_hostelid IN hostel.hostelid%TYPE, 
    p_hostelfee OUT hostel.hostelfee%TYPE 
) 
IS 
    v_count NUMBER; 
    v_hostelfee hostel.hostelfee%TYPE; 
BEGIN 
    /* Count rows in 'hostel' table for given ID */
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM hostel WHERE hostelid=p_hostelid; 
    /* If there is noting in the table */
    IF v_count=0 THEN 
        /* raise exception */
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Invalid Hostel id'); 
    ELSE
        /* select fee from the 'hostel' table */
        SELECT hostelfee INTO v_hostelfee FROM hostel WHERE hostelid=p_hostelid; 
        /* print the fee */
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hostel Fee:'||v_hostelfee); 
    END IF; 
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No data found'); 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Other Errors in Procedure'); 
END sp_validatehostelid; 


DECLARE 
    g_hostelfee hostel.hostelfee%TYPE; 
BEGIN 
    sp_validatehostelid('H5',g_hostelfee); 

    /* 
    **Here something should be done with 'g_hostelfee' variable
    */
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Other Errors in Block'); 
END;
```

If there is a row with hostelid = 'H5' collect the fee for given ID, print it and pass it out.

NOTE: It will work only for one row per ID. If there is more than one. TO_MANY_VALUES exception will be raised.

Comment: What will be the output? given that there is no row having hostelid = 'H5'.

Comment: There will not be any. An exception will be raised: -20000,'Invalid Hostel id'

Comment: There will be output. The exception will be raised and the procedure's exception handler will display the default WHEN OTHERS message.